# How do I send authentication info from Passport.js to my view in React.js in a Node.js/Express.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, passport.js

I just need a simple example of Passport and React interacting. I basically just can't figure out how to get an object with my user specific info into my react script.

I want something with this structure (or a better way altogether that I'm ignorant of):

server.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //req.user holds my user info via passport
  res.render(?)(send my html file along with req.user)
});
```

index.html:

```
...
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
  <script src='/main.js'></script>
</body>
```

main.js:

```
var Something = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    <div>{this.props.user}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Something user=(trying to get user info here) />,      
    document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: You can use a cookieParser and cookieSession and access it on the server like `request.session.passport.user`. Is this an option? If so I can elaborate.

Comment: I would absolutely love for you to elaborate, that sounds like what I'm looking for..

Comment: Okay so hopefully that does it, maybe needs minor tweaks, but happy to work through it with you